# Krull's height theorem in the non-Noetherian case

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra

[**Krull's height theorem**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krull%27s_principal_ideal_theorem) says that if $R$ is a **Noetherian** ring and $I$ is a proper ideal generated by $n$ elements of $R$, then $\operatorname{ht} I\le n$.

When  $R$ is not **Noetherian**, this is not true. I wonder if there exist other conditions, (instead of *Noetherian*), that give the result? Is there other inequalities in *non-Noetherian* case?

Answer (score 1):

One (partial) answer to the question:
Anderson, Dobbs, Eakin, and Heinzer, in the paper "*On the generalized principal ideal theorem and krull domains*" have:

> "If $R \subset T$ is an integral extension of domains and $R$ is Noetherian, then $T$ satisfies (the conclusion of the) generalized principal ideal theorem"